# How to use purrr for extracting elements from a list?

Tags: r, purrr

I am trying to use `purrr` to access the level `formatted_address` from this list:

```
tt <- lapply(c('Austin, Texas', 'Houston, Texas'),  
function(x) ggmap::geocode(x, output='all', nameType = 'long', sensor = F))
```

The final output should be a vector of the elements from `$ formatted_address : chr "Austin, TX, USA"`, namely `c('Austin, TX, USA', 'Houston, TX, USA')`

To start off, I was trying to grab the record for the first of the two elements of the list using standard indexing, and then converting it to `purrr` following [this tutorial](https://jennybc.github.io/purrr-tutorial/ls01_map-name-position-shortcuts.html).

For instance, I thought

```
> tt[[1]]$results[[1]]$formatted_address
[1] "Austin, TX, USA"
```

Would be equivalent to the code below, but it isn't:

```
> map(tt[[1]]$results[[1]], 'formatted_address')
Error in map.poly(database, regions, exact, xlim, ylim, boundary, interior,  : 
  no recognized region names
```

Why aren't these two lines of code equivalent? And how could I use `map` or `map_chr` to create a vector of records from `formatted_address`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you have a naming conflict in your environment. As a result, the `map` function you are calling is another function from another package (probably the `maps` package, which matches the arguments listed in your error code, see [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/maps/maps.pdf)). Try to call the function with explicit context as below. Also, slightly change your syntax because otherwise your return will be empty.

```
purrr::map(tt, ~.x$results[[1]]$formatted_address)
```

Comment: Namespace confusions are common in R. I've started using Hadley's `strict` package, which forces you to clarify which package you want to use when calling functions that have duplicate names.
https://github.com/hadley/strict